# Remove margin in last child

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

My code here:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="pages">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="last">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  <!-- end pages -->
```

**CSS**

```
#pages{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 70px;

    ul li{
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5px;

        a{
            color: @link-color;
            display: block;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}

.last{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I add class "last" to last child to remove margin but not effected. I don't use :last-child because it will not with IE6 or IE7. Hope someone help?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
.last { margin-bottom: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: i remember some author not use !important method

Comment: @user2494232:- Did you gave that a try??

Comment: Actually this should do the trick too. But please don't encourage people to use `!important`, see: [What are the implications of using “!important” in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3706819/1456376)

Comment: **!important is useful**. It shouldn't be your "I'm lazy, and am not going to fix my specificity problems" tool, but to discount its validity is wrong. *Guns don't kill. People kill, brah*

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to add a class "last" the best practice to do this and not write a lot of code would be:

```
#pages li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This way, you don't have to create any class last or anything. The css will look in the id pages, the last li (last-child) and will make it with margin-right of 0.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:not(:last-child)` to exclude the last child. So, for your example, you would have:

```
nav#pages ul :not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

This will apply a `margin-right: 5px` to all but the last `<li> ... </li>`.

Checkout the jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c5kvpoLh/).

Answer (score 3):

In your example it is the `li` that has the right margin but you have applied the class to the anchor link.

Your exiting CSS will work if you change the HTML to

```
<li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: For improved support (IE8) try `margin-left` instead of `margin-right` which can then be removed with `li:first-child. [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/urgqD)

Comment: Using :first-child is not only a cleaner approach, but is backward compatible at least to IE7. Throwing "last" on the last kid is absolutely NOT needed.

Answer (score 2):

neat thing, give it a go, avoids using `:last-child` etc..

```
li + li {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer because it gives a different way to solve hanging margins at the top or bottom of a container having rows of items. We can understand like this  "Whoever is added next to me, should place itself from a margin which means one can use `margin-top` only or `margin-left` if layout is on the same line. `margin-bottom` and `margin-right` leads to an unbalanced container with hanging margins. Thank you so much!

Comment: last-child works, however, this fails when there is an after pseudo-element. To overcome this, the next sibling selector would be the ideal pick

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the class to the `<li>` tag, not the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The output of this LESS based CSS will be one of this - I'm not sure which one, I'm not this familiar with LESS:

```
#pages > ul > li {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#pages ul li {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

The class `.last` is defined outside of this hierarchy. The problem is, that it's "only" a class and will therefore always have a lower precedence than the rule with the id `#pages`.

So either you define it fully qualified like this:

```
#pages ul li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Or you add it inside the other definition:

```
#pages {
    ul li {}
    ul li.last { margin-right: 0; }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/SPucf/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to

```
nav#pages ul li.last {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

and your HTML to:

```
<li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```